# Testing Spring Boot background processing project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are looking to run Spring Boot as a non-web application using `CommandLineRunner` to start an infinite-loop processing task.

It looks somewhat like the following.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackgroundApplication implements CommandLineRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(BackgroundApplication, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}
```

This works when using `bootRun`. If the `run` method fails the whole Spring application closes, which is what we want.

However, we want to create some integration tests which check for certain behavior from the loop. When running an integration test, Spring starts the application context and the infinite loop starts. But the tests never run and the process for running them never ends. It appears that the Spring Boot application is running in the same thread the tests would run in. So our infinite loop blocks the JUnit tests.

The test uses these annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

How can I configure Spring Boot's tests to fork the application?

Comment: What happens if you move your `run` code to a service?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, I believe you are saying run as a web-app and put our loop in a service. That is what we started doing. It works well for integration tests. But if the loop fails and ends, the web-app keeps running with out.

Comment: I was talking about a new class using `@Service` annotation and move the `run` code there. That way you separate the class which initializes the application from the logic (and maybe avoid that problem).